# Cannot run Jest in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocha.js, webstorm, package.json

I am getting an error message:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\keechan\Desktop\NodeJS\my-module\tests\sample.test.js
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
```

This issue only happens when I run via `Run` (`ctrl+shift+F10`).

When I run via the `Debug Configuration` I created, it works okay.

But considering if I have many `test.js` files and I want to be able to run each individual test suite, I do not want to have to make a debug configuration for each one of them.

I already tried:

- installing `@types/jest` library under settings (`Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries`)
- added `@types/jest` as well as `jest` in my package.json

Also, I noticed that it is calling `node.exe` in:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\keechan\Desktop\NodeJS\my-module\tests\sample.test.js
```

Maybe this is the reason why? So how do I change it to use jest?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are not running Jest, you run your spec file by passing it directly to Node.js using [Node.js](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.1/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html) run configuration. Make sure to use [Jest](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.1/run-debug-configuration-jest.html) run configuration to start your spec